# Função no Access equivalente a COALESCE

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Olá. Estou tentando construir um INSERT com auto numeração no Access, mas não estou conseguindo. No SQL Server, MySql e PostGres uso a função COALESCE, mas não encontro esta função no Access.

Normalmente uso da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO CONTA(COD_CONTA, DESCRICAO, SALDO_INICIAL)
    VALUES ((SELECT COALESCE((MAX(COD_CONTA), 0) + 1) FROM CONTA), @Descricao, @SaldoInicial);
```

A query recebe dois parâmetros: Descrição e SaldoInicial. Para a coluna COD_CONTA o valor a ser inserido seria o "MaiorCódigo + 1". A função COALESCE uso para testar se o valor de retorno for NULL, pegará o segundo argumento "0" e somará com "1" caso contrário será o valor encontrado na tabela.

Usei o Iif e até funcionou no SELECT:

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(MAX(COD_CONTA)), 0, MAX(COD_CONTA)) + 1 FROM CONTA;
```

Funcionou perfeito, mas quando coloquei na query anterior deu erro:

```
INSERT INTO CONTA(COD_CONTA, DESCRICAO, SALDO_INICIAL)
VALUES ((SELECT IIF(ISNULL(MAX(COD_CONTA)), 0, MAX(COD_CONTA)) + 1 FROM CONTA), @Descricao, @SaldoInicial)
```

> ErrorCode: -2147467259
>   [Microsoft JET Database Engine]
>   NativeError: 0, SQLState:
>   ErrorMessage: Erro não especificado

Poderia usar outra query para pegar o maior código e somar. Mas tudo numa query só é mais prático. Não sei o que fazer.

Estou usando DataBase.Net para escrever a base de dados e testar as consultas. Criei um arquivo do Access.mdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testei seu script de inclusão e encontrei um parêntese a mais depois da palavra COALESCE.
Fazendo a alteração ficaria assim:

```
INSERT INTO CONTA(COD_CONTA, DESCRICAO, SALDO_INICIAL)
VALUES ((SELECT COALESCE(MAX(COD_CONTA), 0) + 1 FROM CONTA),  @Descricao, @SaldoInicial);
```

A função Nz do Access poderia ser usada neste caso. A sintaxe é a seguinte:

Nz ( variante [, valueifnull ] )

Tente: SELECT Nz(MAX(COD_CONTA), 0) + 1 FROM CONTA

Mais Informações [aqui](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Nz-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c)

Comment: Olá. Ele dá o seguinte erro: 
ErrorCode: -2147217900
[Microsoft JET Database Engine]
NativeError: -530123806, SQLState: 3085
ErrorMessage: Função 'Nz' indefinida na expressão.

Comment: Oi. Pode ser que o erro esteja na função MAX, no Access temos a função Maximo.

Comment: Veja um exemplo em [https://support.office.com/pt-pt/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-M%C3%ADnimo-M%C3%A1ximo-6636b171-56b9-434d-adfd-e1b2a5317b58]

Comment: O "MÁXIMO" ele não reconhece. Usando: SELECT MAX(COD_CONTA) FROM CONTA; funciona. É estranho o Nz não funcionar, em todo site que fui dizem para usá-lo. O problema maior é que também não está aceitando o retorno da subconsulta para servir de valor para o INSERT. Será que o ACCESS é muito limitado?

Comment: Pode ser. De qualquer forma vou pesquisar mais um pouco. Se encontrar alguma saída entrarei em contato.

Comment: Ok. Eu te agradeço muito pela ajuda. Vou experimentar o SqlLite, acho que é um arquivo de dados portátil tipo o Access, poderei enviá-lo junto com a aplicação. Se der certo vou adotá-lo nos projetos menores.

Comment: Fiz o teste com o SqLite. Importei a DLL pro Visual Studio fiz as adaptações no código e funcionou 100% do jeito que eu queria. Vou adotá-lo e abandonar o Access. Mais uma vez te agradeço a ajuda.